How does an entangled state collapse when we measure only one qubit?
I am starting to learn quantum computing and I come from a mostly math background (not much physics). My question is best illustrated by an example. let $\left|\phi \right> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left|00\right> + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \left|01\right> + \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \left|10\right>$ be an entangled state of $2$ qubits. If we measure the first qubit (say turned out to be $0$ for example) and does nothing to the other, why does the state collapse to $\left|0\right> \bigotimes \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left|0\right> + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \left|1\right>}{\frac{5}{6}}$. And more specifically why does the second qubit collapse to that exact state. All I can derive mathematically is the probability for each outcome of the second qubit after collapsing. So, why can't the second qubit collapse to the following state for example:
$$\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} e^{i\theta_1} \left|0\right> + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} e^{i\theta_2} \left|1\right>}{\frac{5}{6}}$$
for some $\theta_1 \neq \theta_2$ (because global phases don't matter). It makes sense if the two qubits weren't entangled because the second qubit's state should stay the same. But in the entanglement case, the second qubit didn't have an independent state before collapsing.

How to formally compute the post-measurement state of two qubits when measuring only the first qubit?
Every projective measurement corresponds to a complete set of orthonormal projectors, $$\{P_k\} \equiv \{ P_1,P_2, \cdots, P_k \}\,.$$
If you perform projective measurements corresponding to this set on some state $|\psi\rangle$, immediately after measurement, it becomes $|{\psi_k}\rangle$,
\begin{equation}
    |{\psi}\rangle \xrightarrow[]{\{P_k\}}|{\psi_k}\rangle \equiv \frac{P_k |{\psi}\rangle}{\sqrt{p_k}}\,,
\end{equation}
with probability   $$  p_k = \langle{\psi}|P_k|{\psi}\rangle\,.$$
In your case, you are measuring the first qubit in $Z$ basis. So, your measurement operators are
$$\{P_k\} \equiv \{ P_0, P_1\}\,,$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
P_0 &= |0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes I \,,\\ 
P_1 &= |1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes I\,.
\end{align}$$
So now, you can compute the post-measurement state after measuring only the first qubit and see that the post-measurement state on getting 0 on the first qubit,
$$|\psi_0\rangle = \frac{P_0|\psi\rangle}{\sqrt{p_0}}\,.$$

Why don't we get the state $|\psi_0\rangle = \frac{5}{6}\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} e^{i\theta_1} \left|0\right> + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} e^{i\theta_2} \left|1\right>\bigg)$, post-measurement?
When you measure the first qubit of your state $|\phi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left|00\right> + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \left|01\right> + \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \left|10\right>$ and see 0, superposition collapses and only the terms where the first qubit is 0 remains. So the third term vanishes, and only the first two terms remain, so now you have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left|00\right> + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \left|01\right>$ (upto normalization to satisfy unit probability).
Now, as you can see, there is no phase difference between between the states $|00\rangle$ and $|01\rangle$ in this superposition, and hence, you don't get the some state, say
$$|\varphi'\rangle = \frac{5}{6} \bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} e^{i\theta_1} \left|0\right> + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} e^{i\theta_2} \left|1\right>\bigg)\,.$$
but get
$$|\varphi\rangle = \frac{5}{6} \bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left|0\right> + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \left|1\right>\bigg)\,.$$
You are right that if we were to measure $|\varphi'\rangle$ and $|\varphi\rangle$ in the $Z$-basis, you would get the same outcomes with the exact probabilities. But when starting in state $|\phi\rangle$ and measuring the first qubit and getting $|0\rangle$, it will collapse the second qubit to state $|\varphi\rangle$ and not $|\varphi'\rangle$.

Thanks a lot, this helps. I understood the part about projective measurements, but for clarification, in your analysis for the second part, you have implicitly used a projective measurement to get $\left|\varphi\right>$? (I mean not intuitively) because to me intuitively (without formally defining measurement), it doesn't convince me a lot

I did implicitly used projective measurement. The way you can think of it intuitively is that you have observed $0$ on the first qubit. So first qubit has been collapsed to definite state $|0\rangle$. So all the terms in the superposition where the first qubit is $|1\rangle$ would go away. and you remain with $|\varphi\rangle$.
